# Failed to connect to tor from public network

Tags: ssl, tor, fingerprint

I was on a public wifi connection a few days ago which is quite restrictive, and I tried to connect to tor but all the connections failed because the SSL fingerprint was not as expected - they all were one consistent fingerprint.

Is this an indication that there is a Man in the Middle attack happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.   (Answer needs to be padded to at least 30 characters before SU will accept it!)

Comment: how can you be sure? could it just mean that all the connections are being redirected to a firewall which in turn is blocking the connections?